# objects that can be modeled using only object mode

Tags: modeling

This is my first time on blender stack exchange but i do have experience using blender. Im actually teaching a class regarding how to use blender but am out of ideas on objects people can make using only object mode. I've made a student of mine make a chair,(pretty obvious) a table, an ice-cream and a simple pencil but he is still not very comfortable in object mode. Any ideas?

Comment: you could use metaballs?

Comment: Modifiers allowed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the usage of Blender. It is about educational research which does not fit the Q&A of blender.stackexchange.com. The advise given here could be more harmful than useful.

Comment: @Leander, what you say was my first though. But helping a bit a teacher won't perturb BSE so much and that can be good to promote Blender via his students (probably young people, considering the subject). So isn't that better than questions like "how can I do 'this' in Blender?"? (but OK comments are not here for a debate...)

Comment: Another idea: you could prepare a set of objects (of various shapes) and propose to build with them (a lego like modeling).

Comment: @lemon I agree, and your last comment most definitely qualifies as an answer. (Add it maybe?)

Comment: @Leander... on the other side, effectively, you are right: this question is not for BSE. So... comments only are good enough to provide what the OP needs, don't you think? (as if not closed, we can comment)

Comment: You can also prepare some simple animations on these 'lego like' objects. Simple things like rotations or scales, so that, when placed by your students, they can be animated.

Comment: @lemon I'm not retracting my vote, but added an answer. I really think your suggestions are very good(!)

Comment: @Leander, good to see your proposal. Thanks for him.

Comment: Why would anybody be comfortable modelling in object mode? I think your student should be uncomfortable because this is not how modelling is done. It can be, but it shouldn't. This sounds to me like "I'm a driving instructor and I have a student who is not fully comfortable driving with his hands tied behind his back." I get it - some limitation can sometimes be a surprisingly useful tool, but there are so many real life limitations in 3d, why make even more up? Limit poly count for example - that happens in real life a lot. You may loose your student's trust with unrealistic scenarios...

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is very unlike Blender.SE I am going to use a tool from other sites. Note, that this answer assumes, that the students have a basic interest and intrinsic motivation.

#### Frame Challenge

I think there are two dangerous assumptions in your question.

1. Students should only move on from object mode, when are comfortable using it.
2. **You** (the teacher) have to provide the **content**.

#### 1. Show them a limited, but varying range of tools.

Moving solids around is too tedious to practice, untill you are a master of moving solids around.

Even for the very first lesson, I would include.

- Materials: Just a single color, no nodes, no specular.
- Edit Mode: Just the basic options in edit mode: <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. They are the same as in object mode, but allow me to modify my starting blocks. Shearing a cube in object mode is complicated but very simple in edit mode.

Only teach the most basic interaction with an aspect. Students who wish to continue without fancy materials won't waste their time. Students are into complex materials will figure it out on their own or can request a 1 on 1. Students who want more faces in edit mode will be motivated to do their own research.

#### 2. Let the students provide the content.

You, as the teacher, can set the task. It can simply be "modeling". It can also have a theme, like *summer, space, vegetables ...*
**Anyone, who is willing to invest himself, can provide content**. The students themselves will have to figure out, what they are able to model and what they want to include in their scene. Dictating their every move will only create an army of robots. Provide help with the tools but let them create their own content.

There are numerous games/activities to get going on ideas of what you want to create, but that is not in the scope of this answer.

*Back to the question.*

---

## Anything

Using only solids, you can create **anything**. Hollow objects seems hard, but who knows what crazy solutions a student could come up with. Give them an example and set some constraints (time, content), but let individuals figure out their individual interests by themselves.

The following scene was create by only duplicating solids. I didn't even use snapping, I just aligned the view carefully. (Setting them up in a scene with an HDRI could be nice though.)

[image: solids]